# javascript validation for ordering of numbers

Tags: javascript

The following code is to check validation for numbers.num1,num2 and num3. The validation works like num1 is less than num2 is less than num3. This order it will follow and it is working, but after displaying the alert message the number which is entered and breaks the order needs to be reset to empty.

```
<form name="validateForm" method="POST">Enter num1
    <input type="text" id="num1" name="num1" value="" onchange="javascript:validate()" />
    <br/>Enter num2
    <input type="text" id="num2" name="num2" value="" onchange="javascript:validate()" />
    <br/>Enter num3
    <input type="text" id="num3" name="num3" value="" onchange="javascript:validate()" />
    <br/>
</form>
```

Code:

```
function validate() {
    var num1 = document.validateForm.num1.value;
    var num2 = document.validateForm.num2.value;
    var num3 = document.validateForm.num3.value;
    var count = 0;
    if (num1 != "") {
        count++
    }
    if (num2 != "") {
        count++
    }
    if (num3 != "") {
        count++
    }
    var numarray = new Array(count);
    var flag = "false";
    var j = 0;
    if (!isNaN(num1)) {
        numarray[j] = num1;
    } else {
        flag = "true";
    }


    if (!isNaN(num2)) {
        if (flag == "true") {
            alert("numbers are not in order");
            document.validateForm.num2.value = "";
            return false;
        }
        numarray[j] = num2;
        j++;
    } else {
        flag = "true";
    }
    if (!isNaN(num3)) {
        if (flag == "true") {
            alert("numbers are not in order");
            document.validateForm.num3.value = "";
            return false;
        }
        numarray[j] = num3;
        j++;
    }
    if (numarray.length > 1) {
        for (var x = 0; x < numarray.length - 1; x++) {
            if (numarray[x + 1] < numarray[x]) {
                alert("numbers are not in order");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript** (you can replace the console.log() with alert() if you prefer)

```
function validate() {

    // get the input fields for the numbers
    var numbers = document.getElementsByName("number");

    /* Alternative
    var numbers = document.myform.number; */

    // parse the numbers as integer
    var num1 = parseInt( numbers[0].value );
    var num2 = parseInt( numbers[1].value );
    var num3 = parseInt( numbers[2].value );

    console.log('initial values:', num1, num2, num3);

    // check that all fields are filled
    if (!num1 || !num2 || !num3) {
        console.log('some fields are empty or not numbers');
        return false;
    }

    // if the order is correct, success
    if ( num1<num2 && num2<num3 ) {
        console.log('success: numbers are in correct order');
    } else {
        // otherwise, check which number is wrong and reset the field

        if (!( num1<num2 )) {
            console.log('error: num1 is wrong');
            numbers[0].value = "";
        } else if (!( num2<num3 )) {
            console.log('error: num3 is wrong');
            numbers[2].value = "";
        }
    }

    /* Alternative #1
    // check if a number is wrong and reset the field
    if (!( num1<num2 )) {
        console.log('error: num1 is wrong');
        numbers[0].value = "";
        return false;
    } else if (!( num2<num3 )) {
        console.log('error: num3 is wrong');
        numbers[2].value = "";
        return false;
    } else {
        console.log('success: numbers are in correct order');
        return true;
    } */

    /* Alternative #2
    var nums = [num1, num2, num3];
    for (var i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (!( nums[i-1]<nums[i] )) {
            numbers[i].value = "";
            return false;
        }
    }
    console.log('success: numbers are in correct order');
    return true;
    */
}
```

**Html**

```
<form name="myform">
  Enter num1: <input type="text" name="number" onchange="validate()" /><br />
  Enter num2: <input type="text" name="number" onchange="validate()" /><br />
  Enter num3: <input type="text" name="number" onchange="validate()" /><br />
</form>
```

Comment: Have you read the question till its end? As far as I understand that was the part that worked already. The question is related to the alert message / variable reset.

Answer (score 0):

I would drop the numbers into an array, and then cycle through checking their values with the values of the next index. If you make it all the way through, you have a good set. Otherwise, you it's a bad set.

```
var numbers = [2, 3, 4],
    inOrder = checkValues( numbers );

function checkValues ( arr ) {
    // Cycle over every item in the array, exclude last item
    for ( var i = 0; i < ( arr.length - 1 ); i++ ) {
        // If current item is greater than item at next index
        if ( arr[ i ] > arr[ i + 1 ] ) {
            // List is not in order
            return false;
        }
    }
    // If you made it to this point, the list is in order
    return true;
}
```

As for resetting afterwards, you can call the `.reset()` method on the form itself:

```
var myForm = document.forms["validateForm"];

/* ... */

if ( checkValues( numbers ) ) {
    myForm.reset();
}
```